# Soundcloud API returns 403 error on some track info

Tags: soundcloud

I'm getting tracks info via the API using the simple endpoint `/tracks/`. This works fine for most tracks but for some I get a 403 error.

For example [this one](https://soundcloud.com/patmetheny/pat-metheny-homecoming) does't work:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/232273455?client_id=<clientID>
```

returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date
Cache-Control: max-age=600, public
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 09 Apr 2016 09:39:00 GMT
Etag: "5a8b3e5cf857d1c73a6ec924804140e1"
Server: am/2
Status: 200 OK
Vary: Authorization, Accept
```

But this one works, with the same client id:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/169170570?client_id=<clientID>
```

returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date
Cache-Control: max-age=600, public
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 765
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 09 Apr 2016 09:34:39 GMT
Etag: "0e64b4946489f72918940be1c559f1ee"
Server: am/2
Status: 200 OK
Vary: Authorization, Accept

{
    "artwork_url": "https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000098499957-8mkrc3-large.jpg",
    "attachments_uri": "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/169170570/attachments",
    "bpm": null,
    "comment_count": 2015,
    "commentable": true,
    "created_at": "2014/09/24 15:23:54 +0000",
    "description": "Urban Flora\n\n@galimatias\n\nCover art by: Oska \nhttp://instagram.com/oskadesign",
    "download_count": 0,
    .....
```

I don't know if it's a technical problem, or if it is possible that the user set some options to disallow embedding ? or some copyright issue ?

On the soundcloud page, the embed link is working... :

https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/232273455&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&visual=true%22

In any case it would be great to have a more detailed response, 403 means `Forbidden`, but why ?

I have found some related issues but fairly old and no responses, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349309/soundcloud-api-403s-on-some-tracks?rq=1) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978866/soundcloud-api-is-returning-403-on-some-tracks?rq=1)

Comment: I can only confirm I'm seeing the same with my client_id. Would like to see a response from SoundCloud team.

Comment: Seeing the same on different accounts. I also came across this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485387/soundcloud-api-returning-0-tracks-despite-user-having-tracks

The answer is accepted, but I'm not sure what part of it. And the option 3 is not it for me (i've tried that other client id, that didn't help). And you already excluded the embed flag, so I'm wondering what can be causing this. Hopefully the soundcloud devs see this.

Comment: I am also having the exact same problem.  I emailed SoundCloud on April 1st but haven't heard anything back.  Maybe reaching out on Twitter would be good?  Unfortunately, I don't know any SoundCloud developers personally...

Comment: I've also found another accepted answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360202/soundcloud-api-urls-timing-out-and-then-returning-error-403-on-about-50-of-trac?rq=1  but still... an official reply from Suondcloud would be nice.